# Persons body angle/rotation with TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to know based on input image if the person in there is standing front/back/side.

I can't look at eyes or something like that because most pictures are from behind but the face is still looking back to the camera.

The best thing would be if there is a pretrained model which does this.

Comment: Hi Richard!  Not sure whether there is pre-trained model for it , But you can create one using teachable machine or Tensorflow from scratch .  You need to put the front,back or side images in respective directory or location for training. Attaching relevant thread for reference.  https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/train/pose https://blog.tensorflow.org/2021/01/custom-object-detection-in-browser.html

Comment: Thanks for this direction, I think I'll go this route!